# Landessprichwort versus Sprichwort?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between a **Landessprichwort** versus a **Sprichwort**?

For examples of "Landessprichwort", please see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=Landessprichwort&lr=lang_de&hl=no&biw=1536&bih=754&tbs=lr%3Alang_1de%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1800%2Ccd_max%3A1899&tbm=bks&ei=pdWLYdHABemPxc8P-9SbmAk&oq=Landessprichwort&gs_l=psy-ab.3...523235095.523238190.0.523238405.7.7.0.0.0.0.169.519.0j4.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.1.133.0..0i19k1.200.GbsNa_mtqJ0).

Comment: @Helge: Sorry, I'm to old fashioned - I don't count a google search page as "various examples of".  Only as "various google hits". Because a google search result varies depending on date, country, user settings etc. of the person doing it. And because the found pages either give you a hint or not what is meant with this word. So I'd rather like to have linked specific pages and their relevant quotes to show e.g. usage of that unknown word.

Comment: Especially a google site that tries to tell me something in various languages that are neither German nor English.

Answer (score 2):

The english translation of *»Landesprichwort«* is:

> country proverb

A country proverb (German: *»Landesprichwort«*) is a proverb used in a particular country.

Like most compound words, it is not listed in any dictionary. You must determine the meaning of compound words in the same way how meanings of phrases are determined: by determining the meanings of the individual parts and deriving a meaningful meaning from the combination.